# There has been an error processing your request kubernetes

Tags: magento2, file-permissions

I am trying to deploy Magento using Kubernetes and when I try to access the application I am getting following

```
There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 7b2c0442c678fc4aebf2889b29313a808742bc6eeaa162d96e5de9ada7f48ac3
```

When I run kubectl -n magento exec magento-php-7cd6df7c98-rngv7 cat  var/report/7b2c0442c678fc4aebf2889b29313a808742bc6eeaa162d96e5de9ada7f48ac3 I get following

```
{"0":"Please upgrade your database: Run \"bin\/magento setup:upgrade\" from the Magento root directory.\nThe following modules are outdated:\nMagento_AuthorizenetAcceptjs data: current version - non
```

As suggested when I try to run kubectl -n magento exec magento-php-7cd6df7c98-rngv7 php bin/magento setup:upgrade I am getting following

```
Use 'kubectl describe pod/magento-php-7cd6df7c98-rngv7 -n magento' to see all of the containers in this pod.Cache cleared successfully File system cleanup:FilesystemIterator::__construct(/var/www/html/pub/static/lost+found): 
failed to open dir: Permission denied command terminated with exit code 1
```

Install.yaml looks like following

```
spec:
      containers:
      - name: magento-setup
        image: kiweeteam/magento2:vanilla-2.3.4-php7.3-fpm
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 0
        command: ["/bin/sh"]
        args:
        - -c
        - |
          chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/pub/*
          /bin/bash <<'EOF'
          bin/install.sh
          php bin/magento setup:perf:generate-fixtures setup/performance-toolkit/profiles/ce/small.xml
          magerun index:list | awk '{print $2}' | tail -n+4 | xargs -I{} magerun index:set-mode schedule {}
          magerun cache:flush
          EOF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happened to me, what I did was **Truncate setup_module** table and then run

```
composer install
composer update
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Hope it helps :D

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the following commands.

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/
```